# get all ips from a text by using php

Tags: php

let's say i have

```
192.168.0.50 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod                             tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
192.168.0.51 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea    
192.168.0.52 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

How i can get all ips to be listed like that:

```
192.168.0.50
192.168.0.51
192.168.0.52
```

I have tried with preg_match but it doesn't work correctly.

Any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, we have ideas. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried with preg_match but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: **I have tried with preg_match but it doesn't work correctly** IMOH it's the other way round so preg_match works correctly but you use it incorrectly.

Comment: @JohnConde Sometimes funny how the question will get `-2` on PHP tag but if asked in `awk` (or other shell related tag) it would be a `+1`.. Why PHP guys are such *haters*? Those shell guys usually have much more plan about computers...

Comment: Why do you think you need regex for this? If all lines start with the IP address followed by space, simple string manipulation should suffice.

Comment: @hek2mgl IMHO - the guy was downvoted as he did not show even tiny proof that he actually tried anything. As for ***haters*** - I think SO users get often pissed since many questions suggest that OP did not even put smallest effort to solve the problem him/herself. Number of ***haters*** (so to speak) are different based on tag - try answering a question on C/C++ tag (while not adhering to newest C++11 standard) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For all beginners, this regex isn't perfect, it just an example how to use regexes. Further elaboration is up to you**

---

Use `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

If you aren't familiar with regular expressions in PHP you should start [learning them](http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

[Online test](http://3v4l.org/SerLZ)

Comment: didn't work correctly, could you check pattern of the ip please?

Comment: works for me.. what is not working?

Comment: ok... I removed my comment and downvote, just in case I am wrong. Do not wanna offend you or anything :). But, here is what I mean: http://3v4l.org/C7VX7 :)

Comment: Haven't you read the discussion below your answer? **I** told you that

Comment: @hek2mgl - sometimes I wonder if it is worth answering to someone with rep < ~100. 99% of such questions are so unclear that it is almost certain to be downvoted with any answer.

Comment: @Artur Yeah, the most downvotes I got on relatively simple questions.. however, wish you all a nice weekend! (yeaah!:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter_var` for this purpose.

For your particular format, you can do something like this (untested):

```
// $string contains the test string
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   $first_word = current(explode(" ", $line));
   $ip_address = filter_var($first_word, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
   if ($ip_address) {
       echo $ip_address;
   }
}
```

Clearly, using built-in `filter_var` is much more bug-free than a manual regex :)

Comment: Yeah, but it is much more slow as you are iterating over every word. Use a larger text and it will be a NOGO. (I admit that my attempt would find 1.2.3.444 as well, what isn't an IP, but it is possible to craft a proper regex for IPs)

Comment: Definitely. But, as I said, using a built-in filter is definitely more bug-free. So, the choice is between the code being error free vs performance. And, I tend towards the former :)

Comment: ... or writing a proper regex.. :)

Comment: Yes. I, definitely, agree about the performance comparison with a regex only solution, but the user nowhere states about the length of the text. :)